# Adobe Flex Combobox as itemrenderer

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, itemrenderer

I have a flex combobox as a datagrid itemEditor.

However, after selecting an item in the combobox, its necessary to click out of the combo (i.e. into another cell or elsewhere in the app) for the value to be committed to the combo. Prior to this, the combo sits 'proud' of the datagrid and the value hasnt actually been committed.

Is there a way to force the value to be immediately committed after an item has been selected and for the combo to 'lose focus'?

Comment: Running an Alert after an item has been selected seems to force the commit correctly...

Just need a method to commit the value automatically now...

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, so easy.

```
this.parentDocument.setFocus();
```